# Find and manage multiple copies of the same file/directory

Tags: software-recommendation, files

Due to my father's file mismanagement over the years, he has multiple copies of same files - worth hundreds of megabytes - copied into different directories resulting in a few GBs of HDD occupied needlessly. Is there a software I can use to locate same directory and/or file and help in sorting them out?

In short, I need something that:

- finds copies of the same file and folders
- informs me of files/folders that have the same name even if their contents are not

Solutions not specific to a particular platform preferred, but not an important issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install fdupes
fdupes -r /directory > ~/dupes.txt
```

This will look for duplicate files (by calculating and comparing their md5 hash values) recursively in `/directory` and write them to a file named `dupes.txt` in the user's home directory.

Comment: Any GUI frontend? There's literally hundreds of files copied, and it won't be easy to check them one-by-one going by each entry in the text file.

Comment: You could use a shell script to move all files in the text file to a temporary folder (or to delete them right away - not recommended). I wouldn't know of any GUI though.

Comment: I need to examine each of the duplicated files...

Comment: Really? If fdupe finds duplicates they are 100% byte identical. Would you still need to check them?

Comment: You got a point, but the directory each of the copies are in is important to sort it out.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try fslint if you need a GUI.

```
sudo apt-get install fslint
fslint
```